# Pre and Post Survey Analysis in ANOVA Excel

Tags: anova, survey, excel

I have a small end size of 6 participants. They all took the pre and post survey that had 10 questions with ranges associated with them. I did not ID the participants. I am wondering how to plug this into ANOVA in Excel to get appropriate metrics as I have tried a few ways that did not seem accurate. The goal is to see if the groups numbers for each question were better or worse after their intervention.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your question:

1. It is unfortunate that you don't have subject IDs.
   Ideally, to see if scores on Q1 increased or decreased,
   you would look at six differences, one for each subject.
   If subjects are very homogeneous as to ability, this loss might not be crucial. But if some subjects are inherently better than others at answering Q1 (whether
   pre or post), then you could lose a lot of information by losing the six 'pairs' of scores.
2. I have no idea what you mean by "appropriate metrics." You only addressed one goal and that is to see if results for each Question go up or down from pre to post test.

Pending an explanation of whether you really mean you have lost the pairs and an explanation of your actual goals, maybe it is useful to explore several scenarios for just one question. [Simulations and computations in R statistical software.]

*(a) Subjects have varying abilities and IDs known, markedly increased scores from pre to post.* The large increase (10 points) is detected with a P-value very near 0.

```
set.seed(416)
ability = runif(6, 100, 200)
pre = rnorm(6, 0, 2) + ability
post= rnorm(6, 0, 2) + ability + 10
d = post - pre
summary(d); sd(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  6.683   9.909  10.107  10.200  11.276  12.794 
[1] 2.065929  # standard deviation of differences


t.test(d)

    One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 12.094, df = 5, p-value = 6.827e-05
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  8.031837 12.367957
sample estimates:
mean of x 
  10.1999
```

*(b) Subjects have varying abilities again, markedly increased scores from pre to post, IDs not known.* Pairs are destroyed by scrambling the order of subjects on the post test. Pairing no longer reduces the variance of the differences. No significant difference is found; note large P-value.

```
set.seed(415)
ability = runif(6, 100, 200)
pre = rnorm(6, 0, 2) + ability
post= rnorm(6, 0, 2) + sort(ability) + 10
d = post - pre
summary(d); sd(d)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-29.547 -26.588  -5.104   7.597  31.466  
 75.430 
[1] 42.57396


t.test(d)$p.val
[1]  0.6719451
```

To save space, only the P-value of the t test is shown:

```
t.test(d)$p.val
[1]  0.6802821
```

*(c) Subjects all have* **about the same ability,** *markedly increased scores from pre to post, IDs lost.* In an (unorthodox) attempt to "recover" pairing, the subjects are sorted from lowest to highest scores for both pre and post tests. The t test shows a highly significant result with a P-value almost 0. The danger is that sorting is
really cheating and could lead to false discovery.

```
set.seed(415)
ability = runif(6, 100, 112)
pre = sort(rnorm(6, 0, 2) + ability)
post= sort(rnorm(6, 0, 2) + sample(ability) + 10)
d = post - pre
summary(d); sd(d)
set.seed(415)
ability = runif(6, 100, 112)
pre = sort(rnorm(6, 0, 2) + ability)
post= sort(rnorm(6, 0, 2) + sample(ability) + 10)
d = post - pre
summary(d); sd(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  5.826   6.844   7.516   7.597   8.688   9.025 
[1] 1.269072

t.test(d)$p.val
[1] 2.665522e-05
```

*(d) Subjects all have about the same ability, markedly increased scores from pre to post, IDs known.*
The increase in scores is detected with a small P-value.

```
set.seed(415)
ability = runif(6, 100, 105)
pre = rnorm(6, 0, 2) + ability
post= rnorm(6, 0, 2) + ability + 10
d = post - pre
summary(d); sd(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.082   6.735   8.560   7.597   8.984  10.128 
[1] 2.559262

t.test(d)$p.val
[1] 0.0007693194
```

*(e) Subjects all have about the same ability, markedly increased scores from pre to post, IDs not known.*
The increase in scores is detected with a small P-value, in spite of the scrambling subjects to destroy pairs among subjects or about the same abilities.

```
set.seed(415)
ability = runif(6, 100, 105)
pre = rnorm(6, 0, 2) + ability
post= rnorm(6, 0, 2) + sample(ability) + 10
d = post - pre
summary(d); sd(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.479   5.241   8.339   7.597   9.127  12.827 
[1] 3.688512

 t.test(d)$p.val
[1] 0.003950126
```

*Conclusions:*  You might start by comparing pre and post tests, even though you have lost the pairing.
If you see a significant difference between pre and post, it is probably real (and possibly understated).
In your report of the experiment, you need to admit
that you lost IDs, so the amount of change between pre and post may not be correct.

If you don't see a significant difference between pre
and post, see what happens if to try to restores by
sorting. If that gives a significant result, you may
take that as motivation to do the experiment over and
keep track of IDs this time. However, you should be
prepared for others to be skeptical whether the effect
is real.

Of course, this answer is a thought experiment based on simulated data. Your real data may or may not behave as
my simulated data did.

Comment: Thank you for this- I deliberately did not ID 6 participants only due to be confidential with their scores, but I do know who had answered which survey; I could assign them a number. I meant appropriate as, I don't know which ANOVA data that I paired is accurate. I don't know how best to put them into Excel to compare the pre and post surveys to see if there was a better result. Most answers did not change so I know just by that, it didn't. But need an ANOVA for my paper. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could protect confidentiality by assigning code numbers to participants or asking them to generate short memorable passwords.